Why is odd denominator necessary to get same genus / "rational equivalence without essential denominator" for quadratic forms?
There is a theorem that goes like this (see e.g. Cox, Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$, Theorem 3.11, where he also lists several other equivalent criteria):

Theorem: Let $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ be primitive (integral) binary quadratic forms of the same discriminant $D$, and positive definite if $D<0$. Then the following are equivalent:

$f$ and $g$ belong to the same genus, defined here to mean that they represent the same values in $(\Bbb Z/D\Bbb Z)^\times$.
$f$ and $g$ are equivalent over $\Bbb Q$ via a matrix with denominators coprime to $2D$.
$f$ and $g$ are equivalent over $\Bbb Q$ “without essential denominators”, meaning that for any non-zero integer $m$, we can find an equivalence matrix with denominators coprime to $m$.



Question: Why are the denominators required to be coprime to $2D$ in point $(2)$ above? Why not just $D$?


I'll give my proof attempt that $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ even if $2D$ is replaced by $D$, in the hopes that you can point out if it's correct or if I'm missing something. Let
$$g(x,y) = f(rx+sy, tx+uy),$$
where
$$r,s,t,u\in \Bbb Q,\quad ru-st = \pm1,$$
and $r,s,t,u$ have denominators coprime to $D$. ($ru-st = \pm1$ follows from the fact that $f$ and $g$ have equal discriminant). Let $d$ be the product of the denominators (or the least common multiple). Then we have integers $r',s',t',u'\in\Bbb Z$ such that
$$
g(x,y) = \frac1{d^2}f(r'x+s'y, t'x+u'y)=: \frac1{d^2}f(x', y').
$$
Assume that $m\in (\Bbb Z/D\Bbb Z)^\times$ is represented by $g$, so that $m \equiv g(x,y)\pmod D$. Since $d$ is coprime to $D$, we have
$$
m \equiv g(x,y) = \frac1{d^2}f(x', y') \equiv f(d^{-1}x', d^{-1}y')
\pmod D,$$
showing that $m\pmod D$ is also represented by $f$. By symmetry, since $\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\t&u\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ is of the same form as $\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\t&u\end{pmatrix}$, the other direction follow as well, i.e. $m$ represented by $f$ implies $m$ represented by $g$ $\pmod D$.

So what's going on here? I don't see any special case regarding evenness of the denominators, but am I missing something? Or could the theorem be stated like this because of some higher theory that it corresponds to? Of, course if $D$ is sufficient, then it also implies the case $2D$ via point $(3)$ in the theorem, but is $2D$ necessary or not?
Vague idea: Could it be a requirement that $x$ and $y$ are both coprime to $D$ for a representation to "count"? I don't think so.

Here is an example you can play with, discriminant $-39,$  principal genus has (reduced)  forms with coefficients $<1,1,10>$ and $<3,3,4>$  while the other genus has $<2,1,5>$ and $<2,-1,5>.$   Your conditions are automatic when the discriminant is even.

@WillJagy Thank you. After searching through a fair range of possibilities (though I've only been searching with half-integers for now), I still can't find a counterexample from your suggestion. Would you mind giving an explicit counter-example, or even better if you can point out a flaw in my reasoning?
